# Find index near mouseX, mouseY with matrix

Tags: java, matrix, processing

I am creating a game sort of based on the Game of Life and Death. The goal of the project is when the cells turn white they will reproduce with other nearby cells, and when they are black they will die randomly. This part of the game I want to implement and have it run based on the state of the cells (`life` or `death`).

Currently, when the cells are white and the mouse is pressed the cell will turn white and stay white until the mouse is unclicked and clicked again. When they are black they will be erased if the mouse is over them. Unfortunately, that also removes the array value from the matrix I use to keep track of the current cells. How can I use matrixes without getting an Array Index out of bounds error? I've tried adding a second if statement to search for nearby cells, but it searches even if the cells aren't drawn. I including the entire code here as I do not want to exclude any parts. For reference, I am using Processing 3 for Java.

```
int value = 0;

int cols, rows;
int scl = 20;
boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[scl+1][scl+1];
boolean life;
boolean death;

void setup() {
  frameRate(25);
  size(400, 400);
  int w = 400;
  int h = 400;
  cols = w / scl;
  rows = h / scl;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      int xpos = x*scl;
      int ypos = y*scl;

      //cell border color
      stroke(55);
      if ((mouseX >= xpos && mouseX <= xpos+scl) &&
        (mouseY >= ypos && mouseY <= ypos+scl)) {
        if (mousePressed == true) {
          //println("Clicked at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
          if (!matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl]) {
            matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = true;

          if (life){
            matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = true;
            println("Living at " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
          }
          if (death){
            matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = false;
            println("Dying at " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
          }

          } else {
            matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] = false;
          }
          //fill(100);
          fill(value);
        }
        //println("Mouse at: " + xpos + " and " + ypos);
      } else {
        fill(50);
      }
      if (matrix[x][y]) {
        fill(value);
      }
      rect(xpos, ypos, scl, scl);
    }
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (value == 0) {
    life = true;
    death = false;
    value = 245;
  } else {
    life = false;
    death = true;
    value = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code, I do **not** get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Your project is getting to the point where it's too big for us to debug for you anyway. Have you tried doing your own debugging? See [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) for a guide. Can you please post a [mcve] (not your whole project) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I couldn't decide what code to remove to make it simplified or to debug it because many parts rely on each other. However, the problem of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused when I attempt to change or make another if statement `matrix[xpos/scl][ypos/scl] ` to something like `matrix[xpos/scl*2][ypos/scl*2] `, `matrix[xpos/scl+1][ypos/scl+1] ` or `matrix[xpos/scl+20][ypos/scl+20] `, which all cause that error.

Comment: Generally, you don't **remove** any code to create a MCVE. Instead, you **start over with a blank sketch** and only add as much code as is required to reproduce the problem. For everything else, use hard-coded values that just show the state that causes the error.

Comment: @Icy4614 Can you post the whole exception text, and explain how to reproduce your error?